# Understanding the proof of naturality in Hatcher's Algebraic Topology

Tags: algebraic-topology

On p. 136 in Hatcher's *Algebraic Topology* (on naturality) he briefly states the following (with respect to the diagram shown below):

> Commutativity of the squares involving $i_∗$ and $j_∗$ follows from the
> obvious commutativity of the corresponding squares of chain groups, with $C_n$ in place
> of $H_n$.

[image]

Somehow neither the claim for $C_n$, nor the reason why this immediately implies the same for $H_n$ ("follows from") are obvious to me.

For the $C_n$ I ended up convincing myself this is the case the 'long way' - by taking a $\alpha \in C_n(A)$ and unravelling the defintions of each map, including reaching the point of using cosets when I reached $f_\#$ (e.g.: $f_\#(\sigma C_n(A))= f_\#(\sigma)f_\#(C_n(A))=f\circ\sigma C_n(B)$).

**but I'm guessing this is not the 'obvious' way he was referring to.
Also - still not sure how this implies the same for the $H_n$.
What am I missing?**

Comment: Passing to (co)homology preserves chain complexes, so nothing special there (it's just a general fact you can prove in the category of chain complexes; it's a basic definition chase that's a few lines long, and can be generalized to certain functors). Regarding $C_n$, just consider the action on a chain; we can either first trivially embed and then pushforward, or we can pushfoward and embed. Since the embedding restricts to the identity on the subspace (note it really *is* a subspace before we pass to homology), both sides of the square are really just pushing forward so are equal.

Comment: As a reference for the first claim I made, my copy of Weibel has it as Exercise 1.1.2: "Show that a morphism $u \colon C \to D$ of chain complexes (i.e. a chain map) sends boundaries to boundaries and cycles to cycles, hence maps $H_n(C) \to H_n(D)$" (note $C$ and $D$ are chain complexes, and $u$ is a map between them filtered in the sense that $u_i$ is the vertical map from $C_i$ to $D_i)$. You could alternatively prove this directly in the topological case, but it will be more messy, less general, and I imagine will require writing out a representative class for the chains.

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen do you want to post that as an answer?

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen Is it an obvious fact that "trivially embed and then push forward" the same as "push forward and trivially embed"? I thought the obviousness would be derived somehow from previous discussions in Hatcher's book (although I'm not able to point to which ones...). Also - I know that chain maps induce homomorphisms on homology, but it's still not immediately obvious to me that the commutativity transfers too.

Comment: Obvious is in the eye of the beholder here. If we consider chains induced on the subspace, then "embed" becomes the identity map, so the claim becomes tautological (As Hatcher implies with the phrase obvious, it's not meant to be tricky). Alternatively, the argument you wrote out works as well. Regarding commutativity, this is the meaning of $u$ remaining a chain map from $H_n(C)$ to $H_n(D)$; the fact $H_n(\cdot)$ remains a chain complex follows from what you said about homomorphisms, while the fact $u$ remains a chain map follows from the facts it preserves boundaries and cycles...

Comment: ... and thus preserves quotients and thus preserves homology (or, in a more abstract context, you could show it preserves kernels and cokernels and is thus a chain map between general abelian categories. The argument using quotients suffices over modules though). It's not supposed to be immediately obvious that $u$ factors through the quotient since proving it preserves kernels and boundaries requires work, but once you know that it does, it is clear passing to (co)homology leaves commutative squares as commutative squares.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Commutativity of the squares involving $i_∗$ and $j_∗$ follows from the
> obvious commutativity of the corresponding squares of chain groups.

For $i_*$ Hatcher has given the argument on p.111:

> Two basic properties of induced homomorphisms which are important in spite
> of being rather trivial are:
> (i) $(fg)_∗ = f_∗g_∗$ for a composed mapping $X \stackrel{g}{\to} Y \stackrel{f}{\to} Z$. This follows from associativity of compositions $Δ^n \stackrel{\sigma}{\to} X \stackrel{g}{\to} Y \stackrel{f}{\to} Z$. [In other words, Hatcher states that $(fg)_\# = f_\#g_\#$ on the level of chain groups.]

Now note that $f_{abs} \circ i_{A,X} = i_{B,Y} \circ f_{rel}$ because $f$ is a map of pairs $f : (X,A) \to (Y,B)$. Here $f_{abs} : X \to Y$ and $f_{rel} : A \to B$ are the corresponding maps between spaces.

For $j_*$ observe that $f_\# : C_n(X) \to C_n(Y)$ has the property $f_\#(C_n(A)) \subset  C_n(B)$. This is immediate from the commutativity of the square involving the $i_\#$. Thus by definition $f_\# : C_n(X,A) \to C_n(Y,B)$ makes the following diagram commute:

$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
C_n(X) @>{}>> C_n(X,A) @= C_n(X)/C_n(A)\\
@V{f_\#}VV @VV{f_\#}V \\
C_n(Y) @>>{}> C_n(Y,B)  @= C_n(Y)/C_n(B)\end{CD}
Here the horizontal arrows are the quotient homomorphisms.

I think this is what Hatcher means when he says "obvious commutativity". Sometimes the reader has to fill in somedetails.

The next step is to understand that for arbitrary chain maps $\phi : A \to B$ and $\psi: B \to C$ between chain complexes $A, B, C$ we have $(\psi \phi)_* = \psi_*\phi_*$ as homomorphisms $H_n(A) \to H_n(C)$. Hatcher does not explicitly state this, but it is very easy to verify:

For $[g]_A \in H_n(A) = \ker \partial^A_n/\operatorname{im}\partial^A_{n+1}$ we have $\psi_*(\phi_*([g]_A)) = \psi_*([\phi_n(g)]_B) = [\psi_n(\phi_n(g))]_C = [(\psi_n\phi_n)(g)]_C = (\psi\phi)_*([g]_A)$.